# Select multiple possible values stored in a column

Tags: sorting

after searching for 3+ hours I just did not found a solution.
I have to modify a script and the scenario is the following:

A  in a column there are multiple different values stored. Sometimes there is only stored only one value. This are possible values:

```
~0~ = for Sunday
~1~ = for Monday
~2~ = for Tuesday
...
~6~ = for Saturday
```

The code for selecting values is currently like this:

```
<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~0~') { ?>
<?php echo lang('sunday'); ?>

<?php } ?>              

<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~1~') { ?>
<?php echo lang('monday'); ?>
<?php } ?> 


<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~2~') { ?>
<?php echo lang('tuesday'); ?>
<?php } ?> 

<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~3~') { ?>
<?php echo lang('wednesday'); ?>
<?php } ?> 


<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~4~') { ?>
<?php echo lang('thursday'); ?>
<?php } ?> 


<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~5~') { ?>
<?php echo lang('friday'); ?>
<?php } ?> 

<?php if ($tripdetails['trip_frequncy'] == '~6~') { ?>
<?php echo ('saturday'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is that for some entries there are multiple entries like ~0~,~1~,~2~
stored some ads in the dataset (= multiple days for example: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday).

So I have to select ~0~,~1~,~2~ and in the same time convert each value to a day name. With the above code this is not possible, because the code was just made for the case if there is only ONE entry in row "trip_frequency" and not multiple values

For any ideas how to solve this it would be nice if you would post your input.
Thank you very much!

BR,
Alessandro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKwXA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for each loop to check the multiple items in an array and then pass that off to a function with a switch statement to echo whatever you need.

Something like this, you can adapt it to suit your specific framework.

```
<?php

$days = array('~6~', '~3~', '~1~', '~0~');
foreach ($days as &$day) {
    showTrip($day);
}

function showTrip($tripday){
    switch ($tripday) {
        case "~0~":
            echo "Sunday";
            break;
        case "~1~":
            echo "Monday";
            break;
        case "~2~":
            echo "Tuesday";
            break;
        case "~3~":
            echo "Wednessday";
            break;
        case "~4~":
            echo "Thursday";
            break;
        case "~5~":
            echo "Friday";
            break;   
        case "~6~":
            echo "Saturday";
            break;                                      
        default:
            echo "Unsure of which day this trip takes place, please contact our support.";
    }
}

?>
```

Goodluck,

~F